# How can I measure segment of a shapes perimeter?

Tags: geometry

I am creating a tracing tool and one aspect of that is that I need to determine the length of a segment of a shape's outline. Given any shape within a 100x100 grid, and two points on that shapes perimeter, is there a way to determine the length of the subsection made by those two points?
For example if I have any of the shapes below, is there an equation that can tell me the length of the segment from the start point to the current point?

I have seen the method of overlaying a circle onto the shape and converting cartesian points to polar coordinates to determine the segments percent of the total path described [here](http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/11/finding-points-along-svg-path-using_2799.html), but it gave me inaccurate numbers when the shapes grew more complex like the third shape below.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Unless you have an equation for the shape, no. At best you could approximate the length of the relevant arc of curve.

Comment: You need the curve to calculate its length. You probably have to approximate the curve by segments of linear or higher polynomial functions.